# How to make the pivot navigate to right or left?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, pivot, gesture

I put a WebBrowser control inside a pivotItem, and a problem happens, the WebBrowser control take over the flick gesture. So the pivot can't navigate normally. So I put a gestureListner inside the parent container.

```
            <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" 
                          VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <phone:WebBrowser x:Name="myWB1"
                    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeExtraLarge}" 
                    wb:WebBrowserHtmlBinding.HtmlString="{Binding MainFloor}" 
                    Foreground="{StaticResource TitleColor}"
                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                    VerticalContentAlignment="Top"
                    Width="Auto" Height="Auto"
                    Navigating="WebBrowser_Navigating">

                </phone:WebBrowser>
                <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                    <toolkit:GestureListener Flick="GestureListener_Flick" />
                </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
            </ScrollViewer>

    private void GestureListener_Flick(object sender, FlickGestureEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Direction.ToString() == "Horizontal")
        {
            myPivot.SelectedIndex = 1;
        }
    }
```

**The code above worked, but the problem is it is always navigate in one direction. No matter I flick to right or left. The pivot always navigate from right to left. Why, and How to solve it?**
[The pivotitem's SelectedIndex of the WebBrowser control is 0, the next pivot is 1. ]

Answer (score 0):

You are not checking whether the flick was towards the left or right. You are only checking the direction, in case of horizontal it could be either left or right. Try this:

```cs
private void GestureListener_Flick(object sender, FlickGestureEventArgs e) {
  if (e.Direction == System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Vertical) return;

  var currentIndex = myPivot.SelectedIndex;
  var maxIndex = myPivot.Items.Count - 1;

  // User flicked towards left
  if (e.HorizontalVelocity < 0) {
    if (currentIndex < maxIndex) myPivot.SelectedIndex++; else myPivot.SelectedIndex = 0;
  // User flicked towards right
  } else if (e.HorizontalVelocity > 0) {
    if (currentIndex > 0) myPivot.SelectedIndex--; else myPivot.SelectedIndex = maxIndex;
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you could simply set `IsHitTestVisible` to `false` on the browser control to disable gestures on it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it seems that the result is the same, whatever I scroll left, or right, the pivot always move from right to left, i will create a new project to see if this is a specific situation when mixed with WebBrowser control

Comment: Are you sure you copied the code above? I have tested the code with a pivot and browser controls and it works as expected. I am not sure how its not working for you.

Comment: while I was try to make the webbrowser control with scroll and auto-fit-its-height-via-content ability, i add a scrollview as its parent container,maybe this is the problem, i will do a test

Comment: I tried with your Xaml in your question and it was working fine. Note that you could simply set IsHitTestVisible to false on the browser and you wont need any gesture events.

Comment: with set the IsHitTestVisible to "False", it works well, but it just make can't do a vertical scroll to content in the webbrowser control, even its parent is a scrollview. And I can't communicate between the inside HTML and the outside XAML @_@

Comment: I create a new project based on wp os 7.1, with the official pivot template. 2 pivot items, with the web browser control in the first pivotitem, with the above code, the problem happens again, no matter which direction you are flick to, the pivot always move from right to left

Comment: When I flick towards left from the PivotItem1, [if (currentIndex < maxIndex) myPivot.SelectedIndex++; ] this code get run, and after [myPivot.SelectedIndex++], the PivotItem1 always move from right to left to PivotItem2.

Comment: I see, it seems the transition animation of the pivot control doesn't work correctly when there are 2 pivot items. I tested with three items and the transition animation was perfect. I am not sure if this behavior can be changed, most likely it's a bug.

Comment: hmmm, it seems that's very annoying :P thanks all the way, Alaa